# Add delay or latency to audio device

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones

My wife is streaming a fitness class and attempting to use Bluetooth headphones to listen to music and also feed the music into the stream using Loopback. This is working well but the stream gets 0 latency on the audio and her Bluetooth headphones have noticeable latency so she ends up doing things off beat.

Using Bluetooth explorer, I’ve tried forcing both her MacBook (2015) and my MacBook (2019) to use AptX with 0.0 latency but there is still latency. I also tried using a Bluetooth receiver that supports AptX and plugging that into the headphone jack on her MacBook but still had out of sync audio to the headphones and the MacBook speakers.

Now I’m wondering if I can add a delay or latency just to the MacBooks speakers, not to the Bluetooth headphones. Is there a way to do this just for the one audio source?

(I’m also open to other solution to this situation in general)

Comment: I've never attempted anything like this, but it might be possible using Loopback &/or Audio Hijack in conjunction, to add in an AU Delay plugin to just the speaker outs. You can definitely inject the delay in Hijack to one of two outputs, I've just never tried it with this type of routing. Quick example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQqt6.png

Comment: Seems like the delay is might actually be coming from Zoom. When I try out the [latency test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRSIvFOzRBs) with AptX enabled I can tell that the audio is in sync. So unless Firefox/YouTube is intelligently compensating for bluetooth latency, the delay is coming from the connection to Zoom because when I record a video with Zoom the latency is still there.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately it's not something I could test - I'm a retired sound engineer so quite used to odd patching of audio routes over the years, but I'm not much of a consumer of 'consumer audio'. I don't have either Zoom or any Bluetooth device I could use as comparison, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Using OBS https://obsproject.com/de and vb-cable https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm as explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8X1kgumf_k can be a workable solution.

Comment: It would be good if you summarize the solutions presented at your links in the body of your answer. AD discourages link-only answers as links often expire, move or just vanish, and we want the answers provided to be an ongoing resource for finding solutions to Mac and macOS problems.